# Feynman rules, Higgs Decay

Tags: standard-model, feynman-diagrams, higgs

How can we write the Feynman rules for Higgs decay to two Standard model fermions?

Comment: What do mean exactly by Feynman rules? Just conservation of 4-momentum, charge and lepton number applies. A (scalar) Higgs line is then connected via a vertex to a fermion and antifermion lines.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable (>57%) way of Higgs decay is to the bottom-antibottom quarks, that is, to fermion-antifermion pair. This is described and depicted using Feynman diagrams in Wikipedia page on the [Higgs Boson decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson#Decay).

Regarding Feynman rules: just conservation of 4-momentum, charge and lepton number applies. A (scalar) Higgs line is connected via a vertex to a pair of fermion and antifermion lines.